# Comparison operator with duration that may exceed 1 day with format h:mm

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet which measures duration that may vary between 0:00 (h:mm) to d:h:mm (with number of days beyond 1). Everything goes as planned until column T "Respect Délai" where I want to measure whether the deadline (délai) is respected by using the formula below :
=IF(OR(AND(S2<="1:00",D2="Imagerie Conventionnelle"),AND(S2<="5:00",D2="Imagerie lourde")),"Oui","Non")
where the column D refers to a binary type of imagery (musn't change) and D refers to a duration in format h:mm (that sometimes goes beyond 23:59).
The formula seems to work for most of the rows but there are somes where it displays an incorrect result based on the conditions set in the IF formula (verified them manually), and I can't seem to figure out why.

Please note that I tried to use the TIME(h,,) instead of "h:mm" but since it only accept values between 0:00 and 23:59, this doesn't seem to work either.

If anyone can provide help pls, I'd forever be grateful.

(NB: You can access the file directly from this link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WFRkoHcie798CAsflsGph7EtlYWbwQLt/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114213074024739188834&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 0):

Set column S as a number field and column T to use decimal values instead of duration and try this:

```
=IF(OR(AND(S2<=0.0417,D2="Imagerie Conventionnelle"),AND(S2<=0.2083,D2="Imagerie lourde")),"Oui","Non")
```